# Suggestions for building tensorflow seq2seq 'lite' model/dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I want to run the tensorflow seq2seq tutorial but don't want to use large amounts of memory. I'm not concerned with performance right now - I'm more interested in debugging. Suggestions?

For background, I'm working with the seq2seq tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html) (and hopefully making modifications):

Comment: Can you give specifics to larges amounts of memory? 100M 1G 10G?

Comment: Do you mean RAM or storage? I first understood RAM, but wonder now if the problem is not to store and work on the 20G of data. If the latter, how about getting that file, slice it to the size you can allocate, and work only with a slice? Of course, performance of the model will suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with much smaller input files, vocab sizes, embedding size and/or num of layers.

Try using smaller training files in [your_data_directory]...

```
> head -10000 giga-fren.release2.fr > giga-fren.release2.fr
> head -10000 giga-fren.release2.en > giga-fren.release2.en
```

Try a smaller vocab size like 1000...

```
python translate.py
--data_dir [your_data_directory] --train_dir [checkpoints_directory]
--en_vocab_size=1000 --fr_vocab_size=1000
```

Try a smaller embedding size and/or fewer layers

```
python translate.py
--data_dir [your_data_directory] --train_dir [checkpoints_directory]
--size=128 --num_layers=1 --steps_per_checkpoint=50
```

The model will perform poorly, but run much faster with a smaller footprint.